# Couldn't load cocos2dcpp from loader

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

I know this kind of question was here, but unfortunately I couldn't find the answer which helped me. Right now I'm struggling trying to launch the cocos2d-x application through Eclipse and Android studio either on device. I'm using default project based on cocos2d-x 3.7.1. Creating the build through Android studio or Eclipse works perfect, but when I'm trying to launch the app on device or emulator, I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load cocos2dcpp from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.FallingBirds-3.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.FallingBirds-3, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
```

I understand that's the problem with some native libs, but I can't find the way how to fix it. Please guys, help me, I would be really appreciate! :)

Comment: are you able to compile a helloworld project ? Did you try to use the cocos console to compile the project ? if you did it please tell more details.

Comment: Big thanks for your response, Hammerh5! Yes, I'll go through  Android Studio terminal to proj.android-studio folder and run the comand "cocos compile -p android". Apk is creating successful.

Comment: Are you compiling for armeabi or armeabi-v7a? Try to add `APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a` in your Application.mk

Comment: Thank you for your response, mromer! Yes, I've tried to build with armeabi-v7a, but it won't work either. Also I forgot to point out.. I've opened the cocos2d-x project in Android Studio as the tutorial says, I mean I opened proj.android-studio, so my project didn't have any classes, etc. Can it be the problem?

Comment: sure. When I compile I use something like: `cocos compile -s /myprojectpath -p android --android-studio`. otherwise your files will be compiled for eclipse

Comment: I've tried it too, and it compiles finally in the right way. But the problem is, I'm still not able to launch the project on the phone. No idea why :(

Comment: another way to check if your .so files are in your apk is to run a command like ´compile ...  -o /somepath/bin´ . There you will find the apk. Install that apk and review that inside the apk there is a file called libcocos2dcpp.so

Comment: By the way, I've read about *.so files but I couldn't find any of them. My project just doesn't have it. Maybe should I put those files by myself?

Comment: do you compile the cocos2d-x core project?

Comment: Big thanks for your response, amuse! Yes, it compiles absolutely fine. But I just can't run the application on the device and emulator either :( Can't figure out what's the problem.